# What do I do with excess contribution to traditional IRA that was converted to a Roth IRA?

Tags: ira, recharacterization, roth-conversion, excess-contribution

I accidentally over contributed $25 to my traditional IRA last year giving a total non-deductible contribution of $5025.  This was then converted along with all my traditional IRAs into Roth IRAs in 2010.

Now shall I recharacterize $25 from Roth to Traditional IRA and then do removal of excess distribution of $25 from my traditional IRA?  Is this worth all the hassle?  Will the IRS care about such a paltry sum?  What are the penalties and fines for just leaving it be? The complication to taxes hardly seems worth the effort of this inadvertent error.

Comment: Oh *they care*.  It is their job to care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a penalty for the excess deposit, 6% per year until it's removed. I agree, it seems small, but send in the form, take care of it, and put it behind you. Easy enough.